# Port existing domain traffic to new domain Azure

Tags: url-routing, azure-web-app-service

I am hosting a website I made for a friend on Azure.  The website was on "F1 Free" pricing tier, but I just upgraded to the "B1 Basic" pricing tier.

Once I figure out how to setup a custom domain name, is it possible to route all traffic from the old url, to the new url I will be creating?

Comment: Upgrading the tier you're in for hosting doesn't change the domain name or IP address. Why should you need to set up a custom domain name and reroute?

Comment: I don't have to, but it would be nice to have a url with the azurewebsites.net in it

Comment: So your entire first paragraph is meaningless information, because your question has nothing to do with upgrading your pricing tier. You actually want to know how to redirect traffic from one domain to another, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that by old URL you mean the URL of the web app (something like myrandomsitename.azurewebsites.net) and by new URL you mean the custom domain that you will be adding to your app (something like: myvanitydomain.com)

if what you want to do is redirect all the traffic from  to  you can do this with URL Rewrite:

Your rule would look something like:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="SPA">
                    <match url="OLDURL" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="NEWURL" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can learn more about URL Re-write and Azure Web Apps here: [Rewriting a URL in an Azure web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630536/rewriting-a-url-in-an-azure-web-app)