# Azure traffic manager, redirect HTTPS://www.my.site.com to HTTPS://my.site.com

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

My marketing team accidentally created materials with an additional 'www' sub domain and I need to see if I can remove it using Azure traffic manager.

Marketing domain (incorrect) [HTTPS://www.my.site.com](http://HTTPS://www.my.site.com)

Desired domain [HTTPS://my.site.com](http://HTTPS://my.site.com)

I only have a wildcard cert for ***.site.com** so at this time I cannot support the 'www'.

If the user enters the 'www' site over HTTP I can successfully redirect to the correct site.  If they enter the HTTPS, or use Firefox that defaults to HTTPS, they will see a certificate error for [HTTPS://www.my.site.com](http://HTTPS://www.my.site.com).

Would a second wildcart cert for ***.my.site.com** help?  I am not sure where I would configure it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate you have should be enough since its a wildcard cert, no need to buy another one.

I think this can be fixed by adding another host-name to your app and creating another SSL binding.

That means you need to add the www.my.site.com host-name (make sure to assign it to the traffic manager url):

[image: Hostname]

And then do the binding:

[image: Binding]

Once that is done both URLs will work through SSL.

If you want to then have all traffic from  going to  you can then add a URL re-write rule:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="SPA">
                    <match url="OLDURL" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="NEWURL" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can look at this other answer to get more data: [Rewriting a URL in an Azure web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630536/rewriting-a-url-in-an-azure-web-app)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Byron.  We tried a solution like this and it got us most of the way.  We still see errors when the user types HTTPS://www.my.site.com.  This always happens in the newer versions of Firefox since they use the HTTPS prefix by default when the user enters a URL.  My cert cannot bind to \*.\*.site.com so that is why I was looking into a 2nd cert.  Have you seen this situation before?

Comment: the above code look fine but when I edit my web.config file and past rewrite code and save the file and again on refresh pasted code disappeared? any logic, site is connected with Azure pipeline