# url rewrite in umbraco on azure

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, umbraco

We are using Umbraco 7.5+

The in the "urlrewriteing.config" it says that this is obsolete and to use ["iis
rewrite"](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) instead. This is a module that you should install on the server. We are running azure, so we cant install it.

According to [this (non-umbraco-advice)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630536/rewriting-a-url-in-an-azure-web-app) the only thing you have to do is to add a -element in the root web.config-file (see link). Is the iis rewrite module already installed on Azure sites?

If so, do I have to make any modifications to my web config (to disable Umbracos old url-rewrites)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yes, IIS URL Rewrite module is installed in Azure App Services by default. It will work if you will just add your rules in web.config. Do not need to install anything
- If you want to disable `urlrewriteing.config` then just make it empty.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlrewritingnet xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07">
   <rewrites>
   </rewrites>
</urlrewritingnet>
```