# URL without .html extension on azure web app does not work

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have got links on my static website. These links are without .html extension.

> https://zodoc.azurewebsites.net/posts/en/selective_blur  - does not work

Error: `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

> https://zodoc.azurewebsites.net/posts/en/selective_blur.html - works fine

How to make it work without .html extension?

Comment: Are you using Static website hosting for Azure storage, or are you using a Web App? In the last case, you can have some rewrites in place that allow users to access the URL's without `.html`. See more info here: [Rewriting a URL in an Azure web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630536/rewriting-a-url-in-an-azure-web-app)

Comment: Any process now?

Answer (score 1):

As rickvdbosch said, you could use **URL rewrite** to remove the .html extension in your URL.

Open the `web.config` and insert the following code inside the `system.webServer` node.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="RewriteURL" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^(.*)$" />
              <conditions>
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.html" />
          </rule> 
     </rules>
 </rewrite>
```