# HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error on Azure app service

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, url-rewrite-module

We are trying to handle URL redirects by using FileMapProvider on Azure app service, however we get the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Web.Iis.Rewrite.Providers, Version=7.1.761.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0545b0627da60a5f' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Does anybody know if Azure anyhow supports FileMapProvider?

Comment: See this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630536/rewriting-a-url-in-an-azure-web-app

Comment: Thanks @KenWMSFT I saw the answer you mentioned however I need to use this one because of more than 10K redirects. Using the aforementioned will lead to a huge xml file which will exceed the allowed size.

Answer (score 0):

There are some Azure services ([Front Door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-rewrite) and [Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-url-redirect-cli)) that can do URL rewrites but they have [limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#application-gateway-limits) under the 10K you mentioned in the comments of you question.  I would suggest looking in the [Azure Marketplace](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/category/networking) for a Network Virtual Appliance you can front-end your Azure Web app with to support this requirement.