# ASP.NET Core url redirect to change domain not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-development-server, http-redirect

I created a web app deployed it in an Azure App Service. Three custom domains are registered for the site and I try to redirect from Domain2 and Domain3 to Domain1.

I tried to use `app.UseRewriter` and used `AddRedirect` options as well as `AddIISUrlRewrite`. Both are not working.

```
using (StreamReader iisUrlRewriteStreamReader = File.OpenText("IISUrlRewrite.xml"))
{
    app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
          .AddIISUrlRewrite(iisUrlRewriteStreamReader)
          .AddRedirectToWwwPermanent(new string[] { "domain1.com", "domain2.com", "domain3.com" })
          .AddRedirect(@"^(www.)?domain2\.com", "www.domain1.com/$1", (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently)
          .AddRedirect(@"^(www.)?domain3\.com", "www.domain1.com/$1", (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently)
          );
}
```

`IISUrlRewrite.xml`:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="redirectDomain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain1.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?domain2.com$" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?domain3.com$" />
            </conditions>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

`AddRedirectToWwwPermanent` is the only thing that is working as intended.

As could be seen above I tried both the external xml file and the `AddRedirect`. None of those worked.

I tried it locally by replacing `^localhost$` but that didn't work either.

Comment: azure web app is using IIS essentially, so url rewrite is the same as well. I'm afraid [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36631234) can help you.